# DotNetOpenAuth - is it possible to login (to google) entirely from code?

Tags: dotnetopenauth, google-signin

I search for the answer last two days, but can't seem to find the (definitive) answer. I need to get the CSV data from Google Trends, in order to do that I need to login to my Google account. So far I tried to use the following code (originally posted byt @user1883833 in [Oauth google trends download CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986758/oauth-google-trends-download-csv-file) :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var terms = new List<string>() {"debt", "profit", "euro", "dollar", "financial", "economy", "federal reserve", "earnings", "fed", "consumer spending" , "employment", "unemployment", "jobs" };
        var username = "your username";
        var password = "password";

        var response = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email={0}&Passwd={1}&service=trendspro&source=test-test-v1", username, password));

        // The SID is the first line in the response
        // The Auth line
        var auth = response.Split('\n')[2];
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin " + auth);

        int i = 1;
        while (terms.Count > 0)
        {
            // google limits 5 sets of terms per request
            var arr = terms.Take(5).ToArray();
            terms = terms.Skip(5).ToList();

            var joined = string.Join("%2C%20", arr);
            byte[] csv = client.DownloadData(string.Format("http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&q={0}&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1", joined));

            // TODO: do something with the downloaded csv file:
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(csv));
            File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("report{0}.csv", i), csv);
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

While the above works fine - it allows only few downloads before "You have reached your quota limit. Please try again later." message, then Google appear to block IP for a looong time (24 hours or more - but only from code, you still CAN download data from the website on the same login, this limitation can by bypassed by proxy - but again, only few queries can be processed before hitting a limit).

As far as I can see - above login, doesn't generate cookies google use in Google trends. I know I can login using DotNetOpenAuth, however the question is: can I login using code only, without rediraction to google login page? I mean something like:

```
   string username="username";
   string password="password";
   DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleLogin(username,password);
```

Is it possible? If not - is there any other way to login that would allow normal quota limit?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.